# Resultado php em um Modal W3.CSS

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, w3.css

Olá! estou testando o W3.CSS e gostei bastante do que vi até que travei em um form com o resultado dentro de um Modal.
Minha dificuldade é quando o evento "onclick" submete o form, ele abre o modal e a página dá um refresh sem passar os dados para o Modal.

[GitHub](https://github.com/adrianorussao/w3.css-modalForm)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>FORM + W3.CSS</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Meu form-->
 <div class="w3-content w3-container w3-blue" style="width: 500px;">
    <h2>Meu Form</h2>
 </div>

 <form action="#" class="w3-content w3-container" style="width: 500px;">
    <p>
   <label>Nome</label>
   <input id="nome" class="w3-input" type="text" name="nome">
   </p>
    <p>
    <button onclick="abreModal()" class="w3-button">Abrir Modal</button>
    </p>
</form>

<!-- Meu modal-->
<div id="meumodal" class="w3-modal">
  <div class="w3-modal-content">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <span onclick="fechaModal()" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>
       <?php
        $nome= $_GET['nome'];
   echo $nome;
  ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- funções-->
<script>
 function abreModal() {
  var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
  document.getElementById('meumodal').style.display='block';
 }
 function fechaModal() {
  document.getElementById('meumodal').style.display='none';
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo,

Se eu entendi corretamente apenas falta a execução do método que abre a modal, que seria `abreModal()`.

Pela simplicidade do código, isso já funcionaria:

```
<script>
function abreModal() {
    var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
    document.getElementById('meumodal').style.display='block';
}
function fechaModal() {
    document.getElementById('meumodal').style.display='none';
}

<?php
    if(isset($_GET['nome']))
    {
        echo "abreModal();";    
    };
?>

</script>
```

Em tempo, se o seu aprendizado é apenas com o comportamento da modal, você não precisaria nem envolver o php, tratando dinamicamente o conteúdo do HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>FORM + W3.CSS</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Meu form-->
 <div class="w3-content w3-container w3-blue" style="width: 500px;">
    <h2>Meu Form</h2>
 </div>

 <form class="w3-content w3-container" style="width: 500px;" action="javascript:void(0)">
    <p>
   <label>Nome</label>
   <input id="nome" class="w3-input" type="text" name="nome">
   </p>
    <p>
    <button onclick="abreModal()" class="w3-button">Abrir Modal</button>
    </p>
 </form>

 <!-- Meu modal-->
 <div id="meumodal" class="w3-modal">
   <div class="w3-modal-content">
  <div class="w3-container">
    <span onclick="fechaModal()" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>
    <div id="modalNome"></div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- funções-->
 <script>
  function abreModal() {
   var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
   document.getElementById('meumodal').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('modalNome').innerText = nome;
  }
  function fechaModal() {
   document.getElementById('meumodal').style.display='none';
  }
  
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```